# Why am I getting a segmentation fault? Valgrind?

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, valgrind

I have written a program to determine the longest common subsequence between two strings. I have tested my function `LCSLength()` with a small hard coded test case and it returns the correct value.

Now, I am reading strings from a file to compare, and my program gives me a segmentation fault. Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int LCSLength(string X,string Y);

int main()
{
    ifstream inData("sequences.dat");
    vector<string> lines(1);
    string line;
    int LCS;

    while (getline(inData,line)) 
    {
        if (line.empty()) 
            lines.push_back("");
        else 
            lines.back() += line;
    }

    LCS = LCSLength(lines[0],lines[1]);
    cout << "The LCS is: " << LCS << endl;
    return 0;
}


int LCSLength(string X,string Y)
{
    int m = X.size();
    int n = Y.size();
    int L[m+1][n+1];
    for(int i=0; i<=m; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<=n; j++)
        {
            if(i==0 || j==0)
                L[i][j] = 0;
            else if(X[i-1]==Y[j-1])
                L[i][j] = L[i-1][j-1]+1;
            else
                L[i][j] = max(L[i-1][j],L[i][j-1]);
        }
    }
    return L[m][n];
}
```

When I compile using -pedantic -ansi, I get the following error: In function LCSLength(std::string, std::string): ISO C++ forbids variable size array 'L'.

I compiled using Valgrind, and here are the errors it produced:

```
==15183== LEAK SUMMARY:
==15183==    definitely lost: 8,624 bytes in 14 blocks
==15183==    indirectly lost: 1,168 bytes in 5 blocks
==15183==      possibly lost: 5,518 bytes in 58 blocks
==15183==    still reachable: 44,925 bytes in 278 blocks
==15183==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==15183== Reachable blocks (those to which a pointer was found) are not shown.
==15183== To see them, rerun with: --leak-check=full --show-reachable=yes
==15183== 
==15183== ERROR SUMMARY: 23 errors from 23 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
==15183== 
==15183== 1 errors in context 1 of 23:
==15183== Invalid read of size 4
==15183==    at 0x38326: std::string::_Rep::_M_grab(std::allocator<char> const&, std::allocator<char> const&) (in /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.0.9.dylib)
==15183==    by 0x388EF: std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(std::string const&) (in /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.0.9.dylib)
==15183==    by 0x100001AAE: main (firstt.cpp:23)
==15183==  Address 0xfffffffffffffff8 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==15183== 
==15183== 
==15183== 1 errors in context 2 of 23:
==15183== Invalid read of size 8
==15183==    at 0x388DC: std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(std::string const&) (in /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.0.9.dylib)
==15183==    by 0x100001AAE: main (firstt.cpp:23)
==15183==  Address 0x100023d28 is 0 bytes after a block of size 8 alloc'd
==15183==    at 0x5237: malloc (in /usr/local/Cellar/valgrind/3.8.1/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-darwin.so)
==15183==    by 0x4B346: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.0.9.dylib)
==15183==    by 0x100002DFE: __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<std::string>::allocate(unsigned long, void const*) (new_allocator.h:91)
==15183==    by 0x100002E42: std::_Vector_base<std::string, std::allocator<std::string> >::_M_allocate(unsigned long) (stl_vector.h:131)
==15183==    by 0x100002E9D: std::_Vector_base<std::string, std::allocator<std::string> >::_Vector_base(unsigned long, std::allocator<std::string> const&) (stl_vector.h:116)
==15183==    by 0x1000030E4: std::vector<std::string, std::allocator<std::string> >::vector(unsigned long, std::string const&, std::allocator<std::string> const&) (stl_vector.h:215)
==15183==    by 0x1000017D9: main (firstt.cpp:11)
==15183== 
==15183== ERROR SUMMARY: 23 errors from 23 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
Segmentation fault: 11
```

My test file has two lines of sequences. I check `lines.size()` and it returns 2. I also `cout << lines[0]` and `cout << lines[1]` and the correct strings are printed.

Can anyone help me figure this out? Thanks.

Comment: I think it is because you cannot do this: int L[m+1][n+1]; 
The compiler doesn't know the size of X and Y when compiled, and the L array won't be initialized correctly. Try initialize with values

Answer (score 0):

your `lines` vector always contains one element, therefore accesing it by index 1 causes UB

```
LCS = LCSLength(lines[0],lines[1]);
                          here ^
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you confirm that after exiting the while loop, both `lines[0]` and `lines[1]` exist? This will happen only if you have at least one empty line in your input file (and recognized as such).

According to Valgrind (do read its output!) - you are doing something wrong from within `main` (lines 11 or 23) and not from `LCSLength`.